# Error occurs in the template of component CategoryListComponent

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, environment-variables, subscription

Error: src/app/features/category/category-list/category-list.component.html:11:22 - error TS2339: Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'CategoryListComponent'.

11 <ng-container *ngIf="categories">
~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/features/category/category-list/category-list.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CategoryListComponent.

Error: src/app/features/category/category-list/category-list.component.html:22:33 - error TS2339: Property 'category' does not exist on type 'CategoryListComponent'.

22         <tr *ngFor="let item of category">
~~~~~~~~

src/app/features/category/category-list/category-list.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CategoryListComponent.

Error: src/app/features/category/services/category.service.ts:5:26 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Decagon/Desktop/sameerAngular/UI/codepulse/src/app/features/category/models/category.model.ts' is not a module.

5 import { Category } from '../models/category.model';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/features/category/services/category.service.ts:18:44 - error TS2339: Property 'apiBaseUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.

18 return this.http.post(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/Categories/Add-Category`, model)
~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/features/category/services/category.service.ts:22:53 - error TS2339: Property 'apiBaseUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.

22     return this.http.get<Category[]>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/Categories/Get-All`)
~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

i want to have my table from my html template shown when i run my angular project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.